# MXML: Default MXML for Different Views

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, mobile, mxml

I have the following default mxml configuration.

```
 <s:ViewNavigatorApplication
    xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
    xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
    firstView="Home" 
    creationComplete="init()"
>
```

Is it possible to have a conditional value for firstView?

I was looking for a way to implement my application in 3 different views for mobile compatibility.
So I would like to create different packages for each views. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define the views manually by using the ViewNavigator - remove the firstView from your MXML and do something like that in your init() method:

```
private function init():void
{
    if(something)
    {
        navigator.pushView(Home);
    }
    else
    {
        navigator.pushView(OtherView);
    }
}

// pass myData as data to the new view (will be accessible as .data property in the Home view):
navigator.pushView(Home, myData);

// remove the last view from the viewstack:
navigator.popView();
```

[This article](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/mobileapps/WSa122979b4619725672e48c412a3e152164-7fff.html#WSe11993ea1bd776e54e19b82b12a43a4fb49-8000) might help

Comment: sweet.. works like a charm.. Guess I was looking at the wrong articles.. Thanks.